# standard on hadoop coding

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig

Can I get any reference of any document which explains about standard of different hadoop applications i.e. HIVE, HBase, PiG, sqoop, Oozie. By standard I mean, the standard / best practice should be followed during coding etc.

e.g. one standard I know that in Hadoop we shouldn't go for large number of small files rather we should go for small number of big files (means by avoiding unnecessary partitions in HIVE tables).

I am looking for standards in other area like this.

Comment: Each one of these technologies you listed have different code to do what you want... There is no standard. Best practice is to keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "coding style" and general coding practices when doing stuff to be included *inside* Hadoop, then https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/CodeReviewChecklist pops up the first thing when googling for "hadoop coding style".

If you mean anything else, then it's clearly too broad question to be answered here.

Comment: I know of one standard that in Hadoop we shouldn't go for large number of small files rather we should go for small number of big files (means by avoiding unnecessary partitions in HIVE tables).

I am looking for standards in other area like this.